# weinre with iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, weinre

I am experimenting the PhoneGap development for IPhone. The environment is XCode 4.1, PhoneGap 1.0. I am using the Weinre remote debugger according to the tutorial provided by PhoneGap, when I run the app in IPhone Simulator, I got this error shown in XCode output:

```
2011-08-31 09:31:15.275 Contacts[898:11803] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous'
```

The URL is pointing to the Weinre server and it works in browser. I can't find anything about the "whitelist rejection" error in google. Any idea what does this mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

whitelist support was recently added to phonegap.
see [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/commit/f0ce1a8910d40ae3e3033b4186d579fa13dcdd64) and [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/commit/f98cecfb1d23473ba851fb83e023a563c28216c9).

to fix this, you just need to add the needed domains in your `PhoneGap.plist` to your `ExternalHosts`-Array.

In your case, it would be `localhost`and would look like this:

just code, because can't post an image:

```
<key>ExternalHosts</key>
<array>
    <string>localhost</string>
    <string>debug.phonegap.com</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that Apache Foundation has taken over the name has changed from **PhoneGap.plist** to **Cordova.plist**, but it's still ExternalHosts, this helped me get Weinre running which makes a huge difference when debugging directly on an iDevice.