# Creating a PhoneGap based project

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have just created a Phonegap based project, but I get the following error:

1.)

```
2012-04-28 12:21:25.862 cordovaApp[1215:fb03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-04-28 12:21:35.028 cordovaApp[1215:fb03] ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS'
```

2.)

```
 Error: executing module function 'setInfo' in module 'cordova/plugin/ios/device'. Have you included the iOS version of the cordova-1.7.0rc1.js file?
```

Why is this happening, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: there's no need to put the suffix Beginner here. Please do NOT use it in your next questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must whitelist the url you app is going to access. To do it, open your .plist file and add an entry under the ExternalHosts key.

Find the solution also at: [weinre with iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260337/weinre-with-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Do you know what is causing the 2nd error message i have included in my question ?

Comment: Does the 2nd message blocks your app working? From http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/8d73df16c12dc4cb It looks like 2nd message is not an error & you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Yes, i have left it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad reference in my script tag in html page, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js">
```

I've corrected to the right version of the .js file and it works ok!